# In Python how many process should I run in parallel?

Tags: python, multiprocessing, python-3.6, threadpool, python-3.7

I am fighting with handling millions of files which i first read in, modify the contents and then write it back to disk. I have a thread pool where I pass how many jobs should be running in parallel:

```
pool = mp.Pool(args.num_processes)
```

I pass 24 as I have 24 CPU cores.

However, as I do so much disk IO, reading from disk, writing to disk. Should I increase the num of processes to parallelize?

Or in that case there will be contention for resources and it would rather slow it down?

Comment: You can simply experiment with the number of processes that gives the best performance (maybe with a small subset of files), as there will most likely be an optimal number of processes where either IO or CPU becomes a bottleneck (and adding more processes will not speed up your code any more). Depending on the speed and type of your storage medium (and your files), IO might already be a bottleneck at ≤ 24 processes.

Comment: I totally agree with @luuk - your best bet is usually to run comparison tests to determine the optimal number of processes.  Even if you think you understand your app's profile in terms of CPU vs I/O bandwidth vs I/O latency, you will often find that your initial guess is way off of what is actually the best number.

Comment: I would like to know why this question is downvoted? I searched and investigated before creating this question.

Answer (score 3):

This depends upon your application's execution profile.  It probably doesn't pay to try any detailed profiling: simply run a series of experiments to find the "sweet spot" for your performance.

Start with an artificially low number, such as 16.  Try the even numbers through 24, measuring your performance with whatever metric you've chosen.
When you identify the relative maximum that way, then try the odd numbers on either side to find the best fit.

This is a common technique in systems.  My team did it to train deep learning models.  We found that we needed to keep a bit over 10% of the processors free for typical OS operations: model I/O and other resource maintenance.

---

**Additional comment from `@Steve`:**

I've done a lot of this sort of testing over the years, and you'll often be surprised by the answer you come up with. I'd suggest that you make it easy to reconsider the optimal number, and do so regularly, as a seemingly insignificant code change will sometimes alter the optimum value quite a bit.

If finding the optimum is important enough to your bottom line ($ and/or throughput), you'd benefit by building a system that determines the optimum and adjusts for it dynamically and somewhat continuously. This isn't a terribly difficult thing to do.

Comment: +1 - I've done a lot of this sort of testing over the years, and you'll often be surprised by the answer you come up with.  I'd suggest that you make it easy to reconsider the optimal number, and do so regularly, as a seemingly insignificant code change will sometimes alter the optimum value quite a bit.  If finding the optimum is important enough to your bottom line ($ and/or throughput), you'd benefit by building a system that determines the optimum and adjusts for it dynamically and somewhat continuously.  This isn't a terribly difficult thing to do.

Comment: @Steve,  I'd like to get all the good ideas in one answer.  Would you add this to my answer (and give yourself proper credit).  Alternately, write your own answer, incorporating my points into yours.

Comment: Sure thing.  I don't have the time now, but I'll work my comment into your answer when I have a chance.  Alternatively, feel free to do so yourself. I don't care about credit.  I am also keen on making a single answer as "juicy" as possible.

Comment: Way cool @Prune!